# How can i change badge number of my iphone app increasingly with push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app. I build the push notification system, and i can set the badge number also when i pushed a notification, but if i want to send another push notification, i cannot increase the badge number of application. Can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, you have to keep track of the badge number on the server side.

Comment: That is also not possible... If you have an app like if you open the app and the badge will br removed... Then at server side we can not recognize that the app is opened and the old badge is removed or not.

Comment: So? Just tell the server that the app has been opened and the badge is now zero...